# How to detect cursor entering and leaving a table using content control ID

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working on word addin using office js
I have a requirement to detect whether user has entered and moved out of a table during review. I have created the table under a content control. What I need to implement if I click/put cursor using key at any column of table then a global variable value will change to true and when cursor moves outside that table then the variable changes to false and I shall assume user has done some change in table(even if they actually haven't) and I shall save the whole document.

Using below method I am able to detect generic cursor movement event.

```
        Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync("documentSelectionChanged", mySelectionHandler,
            function (result) {
                //write(result.value)
            }
        );
```

However, I couldn't find any mechanism to assert my cursor is within a table or outside that table. Could you help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [getSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#getselection--) to get the Range object where the cursor currently is. Then call the Range object's `parentTableOrNullObject` or `parentContentControlOrNullObject` properties to determine if the cursor is in a table/content control. Then use the `id` or `title` properties to identify the table the cursor is in.

Comment: Please accept the answer so it counts as "answered" in Stack's statistics.